# Порядок вызова функции js async

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
  class App {
    constructor() {
        this.imgUrl = '';
        this.fileName = '';
        this.fileSize = null;
        this.id = null;
        this.fileExtension = '';
    }

    async setDataUrl(e) {

        await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            try{
                this.imgUrl= e;
                resolve();
            }catch(e){
                reject(e)
            }
        });
        console.log(this.imgUrl)
    }

    async handleFile(e) {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            try {
                let files = e.target.files;
                let image = files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();
                this.fileName = image.name;
                this.fileSize = image.size;
                this.id = (e.target.id !== 'secondImg' ? this.id = 1 : this.id = 2);
                reader.onload = (function () {
                    return function (e) {
                       app.setDataUrl(e.target.result);
                    };
                })(image);
                reader.readAsDataURL(image);
                resolve();

            }
            catch(error){
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        let span = document.createElement('span');
        let element = document.getElementById('contentContainer');
        span.innerHTML = [`<img class="img"`, `src="${this.imgUrl}"/>`].join('');

    }
}
let app = new App();
let el = document.getElementById('btn');
el.addEventListener('change', async function(e) {
    try {

        await app.handleFile(e);
        console.log(app.url);// Вот тут выдает undefined
        app.render();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)

    }


});
```

С прошлым примером все получилось, поэкспериментировал - вроде бы все работает. Решил применить в задаче. Загружается файл, и его урл хочу сохранить как поле класса. в set методе, отрабатывает нормально, но как только хочу его вывести для рендера, или за приделами класса - undefined... Возможно у меня тут проблема не с асинхронностью ? а с общей корявостью рук ? Или и с ней в том числе :)

Comment: чтобы это работало как ты хочешь, нужно внутри `async` функций использовать `await`. Без этого, ты можешь убрать `async` из определения и ничего не изменится.

Comment: `setDataUrl` там не нужен промис, `resolve` из `handleFile` нужно поместить в `onload` и зачем там `IIFE`? Передаете `image`, но при этом не используете его

Comment: Если вам нужен ответ на второй вопрос - задавайте второй вопрос. Менять вопрос уже после того как на него ответили - некрасиво!

Comment: @PavelMayorov Приношу свои извинения, не знал.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let func1 = async function () {
  /**
  * Что бы функция и правда была асинхронной
  * Нужен промис, завершение которого мы будем дожидаться
  * с помощью await
  */
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        console.log(1);
        resolve();
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
};

let func2 = async function () {
  /**
  * Здесь только синхронный код
  * но так как используем async перед функцией
  * она все равно вернет промис
  */
  console.log(2);
};


let func = async function () {
  try {
    console.log('start');
    await func1();
    await func2(); // await здесь по сути ничего не делает, можно и без него
    console.log('end');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
func();
```

Comment: А вы проверяли что именно возвращает вызов `func2()` в вашем коде?

Comment: Кстати, зачем вообще `func1` у вас объявлена как `async`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov ладно, ладно) Раскусили, я поправил

Comment: Осталось поправить первую строку ответа...

Comment: И `console.log(1)` лучше бы наружу вынести. Нехороший это паттерн - внутри `setTimeout` код писать без `try-catch`, легко ошибку упустить.

Comment: @PavelMayorov пример ведь синтетический, да и `console.log` точно уж не упадет, но я добавил `try/catch`

Comment: Лучше вынести `console.log` наружу. Инструкция `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))` и в одну строчку неплохо смотрится.

Comment: Господа, спасибо за помощь. Я так понимаю, что используя async/await, без создания промиса внутри ни как не обойтись ? Это же вроде бы как обертка над промисами, генераторами... ?

Comment: @NikolayBarda в общем случае `await`у нужен промис, и тогда он будет ожидать его завершение, если после `await` какое-то не промис значение, то  он сразу зарезолвится

Comment: @ThisMan я тут попытался воплотить вчерашний код в задаче, и зашел в очередной тупик, не смогли бы вы оценить грандиозность тупика? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov я тут немного подправил задачу, не могли бы вы подсказать, в каком месте я свернул не в туда ? :)

Comment: @NikolayBarda у вас там каша в нескольких местах